# Why Math.Atan2(-0.0, x) returns different result from Math.Atan2(0.0, x)?

Tags: c#, .net, math

Please, observe (using LinqPad):

[image]

I.e. the statements

```
(0.0 == -0.0).Dump();
Math.Atan2(-0.0, -0.3).Dump();
Math.Atan2(0.0, -0.3).Dump();
```

Evaluate to

```
True
-3.141592653589793
3.141592653589793
```

And the same is in Powershell:

```bsh
C:\Users\ethan> [math]::Atan2(-0.0, -0.3)
-3.14159265358979
C:\Users\ethan> [math]::Atan2(0.0, -0.3)
3.14159265358979
C:\Users\ethan> 0.0 -eq -0.0
True
C:\Users\ethan>
```

World Taekwondo Federation?

Comment: how is that different? you know `-PI = +PI`  in angular direction therms ... if you get both results to the range `<0..2PI)` you get the same angles +/- rounding errors

Comment: With all due respect, -pi is not equal to pi.

Comment: It is in this context

Answer (score 2):

This is as defined in [IEEE 754 Floating Point specification](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF), page 45 :

> For y with positive sign bit, the special cases of atan2( y, x)
>   involving 0 and ∞ are constants which can signal the inexact exception
>   but no other exception:
>
> - atan2(±0, −0) is ±π
> - atan2(±0, +0) is ±0
> - **atan2(±0, x) is ±π for x<0**
> - atan2(±0, x) is ±0 for x>0
> - atan2(y, ±0) is −π/2 for y<0
> - atan2(y, ±0) is +π/2 for y>0
> - atan2(±y, −∞) is ±π for finite y>0
> - atan2(±y, +∞) is ±0 for finite y>0
> - atan2(±∞, x) is ±π/2 for finite x
> - atan2(±∞, −∞) is ±3π/4
> - atan2(±∞, +∞) is ±π/4.

Comment: But how do you know if -0.0 is given? After all 0.0 == -0.0?

Comment: @EthanKharitonov 0.0 and -0.0 are two different numbers under IEEE754. Most operations, like equality treat them as same, but sometimes, they are treated differently, as discussed on Page 3.

Comment: Just curious, how my code can tell the two apart, if equality says they are the same. I mean I cannot just check whether it is less than 0, right?

Comment: @EthanKharitonov `double.IsNegative` will tell you if it is negative.